# How Can I visualize a pivot table in tkinter (text not aligned)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to visualize pivot table in tkinter but the text is not aligned when strings are long.

Example:

```
         min max
category100 1  100
category2000 2  1000
category30000  3  10000
```

My code is something like this:
I have a button and a label to print the pivot result.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tabulate import tabulate
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1250x750")

def open1():
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
    print(df)
    table1 = (pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Variable1"],values=["Variable2"],aggfunc=[min, max]))
    my_label2 = tk.Label(root, text=table1, justify='left')
    my_label2.place(x=400,y=375)
    

my_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Visualize table", command=open1, bg='orange',width=17, font=("bold",15), takefocus=False)
my_btn.place(x=400,y=275)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    root.mainloop()
```

My question is if exists a plugin to resolve this problem.

Comment: Try using a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Using a tkinter `Text` widget instead of a `Label` would give you much more control of the placement of text, for example you can define tab stops in them to ease aligning the text. Here's some [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text.html).

Comment: I tried to use tkFixedFont but is small character

Comment: I solved with Courier